# How to create and delete multiple session, cookies for a particular use who logged in and how to store their logged details in PHP?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am creating a website with several fields i am able to create multiple sessions seperately, multiple cookies separately. But i want to know how to integrate them and delete all the cookies once they logged and to store their tables once they logged in. If any code available with this scenario are most welcome.

Comment: How are you sessions and cookies laid out? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I your question is a bit broad, try narrowing it down.  Also please show some of your code to show what you have attempted so far

Comment: I use session_start();
$_SESSION['user']=$myusername;
to start session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the user's details and make this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($count==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['firstname']=$row['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname']=$row['lastname'];
```

and use setcookie to create cookies and you can destroy by

```
 setcookie("a","Expired",time()-100);
```

You can use my code from this [Sourceforge Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtnet). A College Scenario which might help you.

Comment: You can unzip the folder from the souceforge link available at top to get all the files and db.